# how to extract data of a specific day divided per hour [MongoDB]?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have objects like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab1119b646e371568c8cf9e"),
    "date" : ISODate("2018-03-20T13:46:30.018Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab3b09dee8b862b44d1641b"),
    "date" : ISODate("2018-03-22T13:32:47.067Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab3b0a1ee8b862b44d1641c"),
    "date" : ISODate("2018-03-22T13:32:47.067Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab3c2dcee8b862b44d1641d"),
    "date" : ISODate("2018-03-22T13:32:47.067Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab3c338a0fa5f1160909b1a"),
    "date" : ISODate("2018-03-22T14:52:32.858Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aba386c9a451c3864e54768"),
    "date" : ISODate("2018-03-27T12:26:06.675Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

that shows the visits.

i want to do a graph that, for a selected day, shows the visits divided per hour. So i need to extract datas for my specific day divided per hour.
i have this

```
db.monitors.aggregate([  
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{
      "year":{"$year":"$date"},
      "dayOfYear":{"$dayOfYear":"$date"},
      "hour":{"$hour":"$date"}
    },
    "count":{"$sum":1}
  }},

  {"$group":{
    "_id":{
      "year":"$_id.year",
      "dayOfYear":"$_id.dayOfYear"
    },
    "dailyCount":{"$sum":"$hourlyCount"},
    "hourlyData":{"$push":{"hour":"$_id.hour","count":"$count"}}
  }}
])
```

this divide all the visits per day and per hour, but i need just one specific day divided per hour.

Comment: Please post sample data set that you're using with multiple documents in it.

Comment: i edited with more examples of my objects in the collection

Comment: `__v` is this your field fr number of visits??

Comment: nope, is a variable that mongo creates for every object. every single object is a visit, distincted by the ISODate.

Comment: And what is `hourlyCount`, I'm not seeing that in the posted query as well as in data set. can I ignore that?

Comment: And what do you mean by  `visits on specific day divided per hour`? 
What do you want to figure out? `visits per day` or `visits per hour`? There's nothing like `visits on a day divided by hour`

Comment: if i choose a day from the graph, i need to extract all the visits in that specific day and divide it per hour. in another case, i also need to extract datas by a specific month and divide it per every day of that month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have all the aggregation code that outputs all the visits across all day. You can add the matching stage in the beginning of the pipeline to limit the aggregation to specific day.

Something like in mongo shell

```
{$match:{date:{$gte:ISODate("2018-03-22T00:00:00.000Z"), $lt:ISODate("2018-03-22T11:59:59.999Z")}}}
```

For aggregating on months you just need to extend the date range, for ex march month.

```
 {$match:{date:{$gte:ISODate("2018-03-01T00:00:00.000Z"), $lt:ISODate("2018-03-31T11:59:59.999Z")}}}
```

and rewrite the query to below.

```
{"$group":{
    "_id":{
      "year":{"$year":"$date"},
      "dayOfMonth":{"$dayOfMonth":"$date"}
    },
    "count":{"$sum":1}
  }},

  {"$group":{
    "_id":{
      "year":"$_id.year"
    },
    "monthlyCount":{"$sum":"$count"},
    "dailyData":{"$push":{"day":"$_id.dayOfMonth","count":"$count"}}
  }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this way to exactly pinpoint to a specific date.

```
// If your specific date is 20-03-2018
var DAY = 20;
var MONTH = 03;
var YEAR = 2018;
db.checkDate.aggregate([
  {$project: {day: {$dayOfMonth: "$date"}, month: {$month: "$date"}, year: 
    {$year: "$date"},hour: {$hour: "$date"}}},
  {$match: { day: DAY, month: MONTH, year: YEAR}},
  {$group: { _id: {hour: "$hour"}, visits: {$sum: 1}}}
])
```